# Какие есть ресурсы для тренировки в CTF?

Tags: безопасность

Просто решил, что хочу поучаствовать в соревнованиях, но не знаю, где потренироваться перед ними. Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: https://ctf.hacker101.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне нравится работать на http://ctflearn.com
Но возможно, вам придется по душе что-то из списка ниже:

1. http://hackthebox.eu/ - правда там есть нюанс: что бы начать что-то делать, нужно взломать сайт и найти ссылку-приглашение
2. http://hackerone.com
3. http://root-me.org/ru
4. http://securitytube.net - очень много всяких разных видео курсов по теме иб
5. http://sectools.org - топ для новичков

Вот весь мой список. Удачи в начинаниях :)

Comment: первый вариант самый крутой, я когда-то [обучалку](http://www.pythonchallenge.com) проходил в таком же духе, новый урок после решения предыдущего, а для этого нужно было рыть везде в том числе и в сорцах страницы

Comment: Да, очень классный формат)